# Gravity in HTML5 canvas game is ruining my collision

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bug in a canvas game I'm working on. The problem is when the player touches the block, the collision and gravity make the player seem unstable and makes it look weird.

Here's my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c1"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  width = 400,
  height = 400,
  player = {
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    width: 10,
    height: 10
  },
  keys = [];

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var block = {
  width: 25,
  height: 25,
  x: 300,
  y: 300
};


function update() {

  if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
    player.y -= 5;
  }

  if (keys[39]) {
    player.x += 5;
  }
  if (keys[37]) {
    player.x -= 5;
  }
  if (keys[40]) {
    player.y += 5;
  }


  if (player.width + player.x > 400) {
    player.x -= 5;
  }

  if (player.width + player.x < 10) {
    player.x += 5;
  }

  if (player.height + player.y < 10) {
    player.y += 5;
  }

  if (player.height + player.y > 400) {
    player.y -= 5;
  }

  if (player.x < block.x + block.width && player.x + player.width >
    block.x &&
    player.y < block.y + block.height && player.y + player.height >
    block.y) {
    console.log("The objects are touching");
    player.y = player.y - 7;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height);

  function gravity() {
    if (player.y < 390) {

      player.y = player.y + 2;

    }
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  requestAnimationFrame(gravity);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  update();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  margin 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: why are you calling `requestAnimationFrame` twice, with different functions?

Comment: actually when i take off the requestAnimationFrame(gravity); it stops calling the gravity function

Comment: probably because if they touch you set `player.y = player.y - 7;` ... player touches block, code raises player by 7 pixels, gravity makes player drop, player touches block, code raises player by 7 pixels, gravity makes player drop, player touches block, code raises player by 7 pixels, gravity makes player drop ... etc - try `player.y = block.y - player.height;` instead

Comment: @JaromandaX i know that but i want to figure out to balance those out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:

- changed touching logic to place player on top of box when touching, offset y's by height of player, sits the player on top of box
- added a flag `wasTouching` to stop constant console logging (so the console doesn't get bombed, and gravity doesn't try to push the player down when it's on the box)
- stop gravity when touching
- changed logic to detect touch `player.y + player.height >= block.y` rather than `player.y + player.height > block.y` - because player sits on top of block when touching, not one pixel inside block

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c1"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  width = 400,
  height = 400,
  player = {
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    width: 10,
    height: 10
  },
  keys = [];

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var block = {
  width: 25,
  height: 25,
  x: 300,
  y: 300
};

var wasTouching = false;

function update() {

  if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
    player.y -= 5;
  }

  if (keys[39]) {
    player.x += 5;
  }
  if (keys[37]) {
    player.x -= 5;
  }
  if (keys[40]) {
    player.y += 5;
  }


  if (player.width + player.x > 400) {
    player.x -= 5;
  }

  if (player.width + player.x < 10) {
    player.x += 5;
  }

  if (player.height + player.y < 10) {
    player.y += 5;
  }

  if (player.height + player.y > 400) {
    player.y -= 5;
  }

  if (player.x < block.x + block.width && player.x + player.width > block.x &&
      player.y < block.y + block.height && player.y + player.height >= block.y) {
    if(!wasTouching) {
      console.log("The objects are touching");
    }
    player.y = block.y - player.height;
    wasTouching = true;
  } else {
    wasTouching = false;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height);

  function gravity() {
    if (player.y < 390 && !wasTouching) {

      player.y = player.y + 2;

    }
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  requestAnimationFrame(gravity);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  update();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  margin 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: yes, strange behaviour was present in original code too

Comment: @JaromandaX I am speechless you are a legend Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jojo - I'm not sure of the exact logic you are looking for - but it's fairly easy to prevent the "player" from moving through the box from any direction ... at the moment, as soon as the player touches the box, the player is placed on top of the box - however, that may well be your intent (as it appears to be in the logic of your code) all I did was stop the player from jumping about on top of the box :p

Comment: @JaromandaX If you could help me with that,that would be great but i am not forcing you but i still thank you for fixing my bug